# What is this?! $(multiple parameters?)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create some html elements with jQuery and i found this bit of code over the internet but i simply couldn't find any explanations or documentations on it (i've only just begun to learn jQuery) or i didn't knew how to search:

```
.after($('<div />', {
    class: 'test',
    text: "a div",
    click: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test")
    }}));
```

I know that .after() creates and adds an element after a specific html element, but i've only seen it used like this `.after("<tag>some text here</tag")` I have no idea were did that person get those key: value pairs. Are they "standard"? Does a list exist on the internet? What did he actually did there? How can i look for what's written between $() on the internet? I've tried something like "$() arguments jquery", ".after() multiple parameters jquery" and others but didn't find anything to make sense to me. I'd appreciate some light on this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: It just means a div with the class test with text a div and a click function

Comment: Folks, the downvoting's a bit harsh, isn't it? We were all new at things once, and you throw a function with a symbol for a name and a little-used feature into it... (Yes, a thorough read of the documentation would find it...)

Comment: Why so many downvotes? She is eager to learn and couldn't find a useful documentations/resources to understand the code snippet.

Comment: If you're new to jQuery, I strongly suggest reading [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It literally takes just an hour, maybe two, and it includes a **huge** amount of really useful information. After doing it, you might consider doing it again a week later, as your understanding of things will have moved on a lot and you'll take more in. Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just `after` with an argument that's the result of calling `$()` with an HTML string to parse and additional properties to set; see [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) for details. It's basically like doing this:

```
var newElement = $('<div />');
newElement.addClass('test');
newElement.text("a div")
newElement.on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("test")
});
whateverWasHere.after(newElement);
```

Comment: So the keys "class", "text", "click" would be the same as some jquery functions names. If this is true, can it be applied each time you want to set some attributes in this manner ? Or the keys names can be randomly chosen? This page http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject or this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes didn't  clear things much. Also, thank you for your understanding! Nice to have people on the internet who actually help instead of jumping to criticism and doing nothing constructive overall.

Comment: @Irina: The docs you linked *do* cover what the keys are: *"As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument to jQuery() can accept a plain object consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed to the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method."* and *"As of jQuery 1.4, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: `val`, `css`, `html`, `text`, `data`, `width`, `height`, or `offset`."* By "called" they mean given as keys, as `text` was in your example.